# Difference between played and rendered animation

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I face a really odd thing When rendering a scene the output AVI file is very different from the animation I see inside blender. The script is looping over a function which create the scene:

```
    def main(self):
        for i in range(self.n_scenes):
            valid_scene = False
            while not valid_scene:
                self.clean_scene()
                valid_scene = self.create_scene()
            if len(os.listdir(self.output_path)):
                self.render_scene(f'{len(os.listdir(self.output_path))}.avi')
            else:
                self.render_scene('0.avi')
```

For example the initial position of the objects is really different from what I see in blender, in addition from the 2nd frame the locations are different from the first frame. 
Before rendering I bake all the objects using `bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all()` and for cleaning the scene after each render using the following funciton:

```
    def clean_scene(self):
        bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any why to reset the scene? why there is a difference between played animation over blender and the rendered one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!
After completing the rendering of the scene you should free the bake of the objects by using: `bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake_all()`

Hope that help to other ones as well.